# Warning: include(): Failed opening failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

> Warning: include(/home/sarvadcu/public_html/paradisetourism.co.in/wp-content/themes/midway/functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sarvadcu/public_html/paradisetourism.co.in/wp-settings.php on line 329
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/sarvadcu/public_html/paradisetourism.co.in/wp-content/themes/midway/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/altphp54/lib/php') in /home/sarvadcu/public_html/paradisetourism.co.in/wp-settings.php on line 329
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sarvadcu/public_html/paradisetourism.co.in/wp-settings.php:329) in /home/sarvadcu/public_html/paradisetourism.co.in/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

Comment: So your permissions are wrong. Fix them. They need to be at least readable all the way to the file by the user running PHP / the web server.

Comment: Use relative path to include files and check file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with template path ,on here template function file not get proper path from wp-setting.php.

try to check out that path Or function file path .on theme activation.

when theme activate that time it find function.php file but it not get correctly so that.this error come.